# "System cannot find path specified" when it exists and has all permissions on windows, in R

Tags: r

I am working locally out of a folder on my desktop and I recently decided to organize the outputs of my script into separate folders at the top of my script:

```
dir.create(file.path("analysis/plots"), showWarnings = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)
dir.create(file.path("analysis/tables"), showWarnings = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)
```

When I save to `analysis/tables`, I get absolutely no error whatsoever:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
    if (i == 1) {
        write.csv(twas_z_amyg_threshold, file = "analysis/tables/amygdala_twas_significant_genes_zscore.csv")
    } else {
        write.csv(twas_z_sacc_threshold, file = "analysis/tables/sacc_twas_significant_genes_zscore.csv")
    }
}
```

However, a bit further down, when I try to save an interactive plot, it gives me the following error:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
 
...

    saveWidget(fin_plot[[i]],
        paste0(
            "analysis/plots/","BIP_TWAS_",
            ifelse(i == 1, "Amygdala", "sACC"),
            "_ManhattanPlotly.html"
        ))
}
```

```
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="analysis/plots": The system cannot find the path specified
```

I am able to see into this path from my `wd`:

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/*****/Desktop/twas_plots"
> dir()
[1] "analysis"              "generate_twas_plots.R" "rda"                  
> dir("analysis/")
[1] "plots"  "tables"
> dir("analysis/plots")
[1] "BIP_TWAS_Amygdala_ManhattanPlotly_files" "BIP_TWAS_ManhattanPlot.pdf"
```

In fact, before this point in the script, I was even able to successfully save a static plot to that path, `BIP_TWAS_ManhattanPlot.pdf`, as you can see above.

I have absolutely no problem saving into my current `wd` using the `saveWidget()` function, which is what I had been doing before I decided to organize my outputs.

I've heard it's good practice to wrap your paths with `file.path()`, something I need to get into the habit of doing considering that I work back and forth between my local desktop and the cluster. This does not fix the problem, nor does changing `/` to `\\`.

If I right-click on the folder and go to `Properties`, I see that `Read-Only` is checked for both the base as well as the `analysis` and `plots` directories. If I uncheck it and apply, and then later re-open `Properties`, I find that it's checked again.

Any suggestions? I could always save to my present directory and then later move it, but I just want to know what this problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You must take into account the scope of the source folder to save a file, every time you want to navigate between different directories you must use the following command:

```
setwd(_PATH_)
```